# Weird wireframe display on viewport when in camera (or certain angle maybe)

Tags: 3d-view, camera, opengl, wireframe

Weird wireframe display on viewport when in camera (or certain angle maybe)

It happens with a certain camera, but it is not like this in perspective view, and I do not think this is overlapping vertices.

May I know what might solve this? I need to show this to my school's presentation and I want my wireframe in my OpenGL render to look clean.

[image]

[image]